# redirect rule not executed

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, rule

I have the following redirect rule tested with rubular.com

```
^tags\/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\.html
```

and using as example  `/tags/a-led.html` is returning `/tags/a-led`. Till this point everything looks all right but when I apply the rule in my htaccess as it follows

```
 RewriteRule ^tags\/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\.html$  /tags/$1 [R,L]
```

and some other rules are after

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(d*)-(.*)\.html$  /showthread.php?$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(d*)-(.*)\.html$ /threads/$2 [R,L]
```

is not getting executed and unfortunately I don't have a glue what could be the reason.

Comment: have you turned rewrite engine on??

Comment: yes is turned on. I have couple of other rules over there

Comment: Just so it's clear, when you go to `http://yourdomain.com/tags/a-led.html` you *don't* get redirected (as in the URL in your browser's address bar changes) to `http://yourdomain.com/tags/a-led`? But the other redirects work?

Comment: no it's not happening that my other redirects seems to be okay

Answer (score 0):

1. The rule looks fine, it works when I place it in a blank htaccess file with a default install of apache.
2. Make sure you have mod_rewrite loaded and you've turned on the rewrite engine (`RewriteEngine On`).
3. If you have other rules, make sure your redirect rule is before rules that do internal rewrites or routing.
4. Make sure your htaccess file is even bring read. You'll need to have the proper setting for `AllowOverride` in your server/vhost config. Setting `AllowOverride All` will ensure everything in htaccess files get applied.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^tags\/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\.html$  /tags/$1 [R,L]
```

also check if you have any other rules set before this one with **[R,L]**. The L tells apache not to process any more rules if this one matched.